# Reaching 'tickets' that belongs to 'projects' that a user owns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

In the project management app I'm working on, I'm currently working on a page for managing tickets, which I want should contain of the following:

```
- The tickets that the user has created
- The tickets that belongs to projects that the user has created
```

The tricky part is to use the right code in the controller, which is where I need help.
'@users_tickets'works fine, as well as '@owned_projects'. However, the last thing which is creating an array that contains of the tickets that belongs projects that the user owns, is something I need help me (yes, I understand that my poor try with an each loop is totally the wrong way to go here).

How can I achieve what I want?

**Tickets controller:**

```
1.    def manage
2.      @users_tickets = Ticket.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
3.      @owned_projects = Project.where(:user_id => current_user)
4.
5.      @owned_projects.each do |project|
6.          @tickets_for_owned_projects = Ticket.where(:project_id => project.id)
7.      end
8.    end
```

#### Tables:

**tickets table:**

```
project_id
ticket_status_id
user_id
title
description
start_date
end_date
```

**projects table:**

```
user_id
title
description
start_date
end_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a `has_many` association, then it should as simple as

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :project_tickets, through: :projects, class_name: 'Ticket', source: :tickets
  #...
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
  #...
end

# in tickets controller
def manage
  @tickets = current_user.tickets
  @tickets_for_owned_projects = current_user.project_tickets
end
```

**UPD**: The approach above should work. I'm literally falling asleep right now and can't define what is wrong here. Would really appreciate if someone looked into it.

Here's another way around though.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :tickets  

  def project_tickets
    result = []  
    self.projects.each do |project|
      result << project.tickets
    end
    result.flatten
  end
  #...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my User model I have 'has_many :tickets'. Can I keep this and have one with through: :projects as well? I want to be able to render out both the tickets that the user has created and the ones that's through projects.

Comment: I get the following error: "Could not find the source association(s) :ticket in model Project. Try 'has_many :project_tickets, :through => :projects, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :users, :user, or :tickets?"

Comment: In project I have the following: belongs_to :user
  has_many :tickets, :dependent => :destroy

Comment: Yeah, I've omitted that. Just specify `source: :tickets` as Rails suggests you and everything should be fine.

Comment: No more error message, but actually no output (with each) on @tickets_for_owned_projects (@tickets work's as supposed). Very strange because I can see in the database that there are tickets for projects that the user I'm logged in with owns. :/

Comment: from the log file: "tickets_for_owned_projects: []
  Ticket Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets" WHERE "tickets"."user_id" = 8"

Comment: What do you think, does the SQL look ok or is it something shady about it?

Comment: No, that's not what I expected to see. Updated the answer again.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot for your help. Very kind! However, I assume both work as you say because the last one didn't work either first so I found out that I had "has_and_belongs_to_many :projects" not "has_many :projects" in the user model. I added the latter and it worked.